# Use variable on calling a method PHP

Tags: php, class, methods, instagram

How can we use variable in classes name on call?
For example i have a class That called like this:

```
<?php
$ig = new Instagram();
$ig->people->getIdByName("param1",array('a','b','c'),"param2");
```

So how can i call this method like this?:

```
<?php
 $ig = new Instagram();

 $main = 'people';
 $sub = 'getIdByName';
 $content = '"param1",array('a','b','c'),"param2"';

 $ig->$main->$sub($content);
```

Comment: Why would you want to call it like that?

Comment: @Andrew I want to create a simple api for a library. and get the variables using $_GET[];

Comment: you are aware that Instagram will be deprecating their api this year, right? https://www.instagram.com/developer/

Comment: I see. That approach is a bit messy and very prone to errors(what happens if you pass a param that doesn't exist as a function in the api). You'd be better of using a switch(or an if) for pre-determined functions.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner Really!? Does it mean that there is no ways to use InstagramAPI for any service? I think you're wrong

Comment: I guess you'll find out in July then.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Methods calls would work just like you showed in the question. So this part of code is OK:

```
$main = 'people';
$sub = 'getIdByName';

$ig->$main->$sub();
```

What about last method's arguments, there 2 options:

**PHP >= 5.6**

[Variadic parameters](http://php.net/manual/en/migration56.new-features.php) were introduced in PHP 5.6, so you can save your arguments as an array, and just pass them with `...`:

```
$args = ["param1",['a','b','c'],"param2"];
$ig->$main->$sub(...$args);
```

**PHP < 5.6**

In this case you should use [call_user_func_array()](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.call-user-func-array.php)

```
$main = 'people';
$sub = 'getIdByName';
$args = ["param1",['a','b','c'],"param2"];

$main = $ig->$main;
call_user_func_array([$main, $sub], $args];
```

Although @Andrew is right, this approach is not flexible and must not be used as an architecture for API providers.

Comment: Any comments regarding the downvoting?